# Return stored procedure result in function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

I have a complex stored procedure whose results I need to retrieve in a view somehow.  The end user is requesting the results to be linked in an Excel spreadsheet and I can only link views and tables in Excel.

I know you can fudge your way through this somehow using `openquery` but it seems like that is not a desirable way of going about this and even when I tested this, I got errors in return.

I can always dump the results into a table that's occasionally refreshed but the user is pretty intent on having this data live on demand.

The other way seems to be through a function.  I tried this but no matter how I slice it I can't seem to get the function to accept a stored procedure.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_testFunction
(
    @Parameter INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    EXEC sp_testProdedure @Parameter
)

GO
```

Is something like the above even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't EXEC within a function. Well, there is one workaround (you mentioned it), but I don't recommend it:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12745/1186

So you should consider moving your complex logic from a procedure to a table-valued function, then both your view and the procedure could reference that, you still only have one version to maintain, and everyone is happy...

Comment: Can I use all stored procedure logic in a table-valued function?  i.e. case, if, etc?  I assume I can then select from this function in a view which I can then link to Excel correct?

Comment: You can use a lot, but not all (e.g. if your stored procedure uses EXEC, you can't port that directly). Also there is a big difference between a multi-statement function (which would have an explicit table declaration, IF, etc.) and an inline table-valued function (which just says RETURN (this result set). The latter is going to perform extremely well, the former will not. And yes, there shouldn't be any roadblocks to wrapping CREATE VIEW AS around a SELECT from a table-valued function of either flavor.

Comment: Basically I am using a cache table to perform a bunch of complex arithmetic operations on financial data and when complete I run a select on this cache table which is displayed to the user on our intranet.  I assume I can just wrap it in a table-valued function and select the results into the table parameter which gets returned at the end?  Thanks again.

Comment: By `cache table` do you mean a #temp table? If so, you might start thinking about doing it all in a single query rather than staging data and working on it...

Comment: No, it's not a temp table.  For reporting reasons I need to use an actual table that I can reference in some ASP code to properly show totals and what not.  The table has a user ID and randomly generated "session" key to separate out requests.  I'm thinking I don't have to change the logic much at all, just perform all the same operations, then select into the functions table to be returned.

Comment: If you show the logic of your stored procedure (in a new question, or I suppose you could update this one since I'm the only one with a real answer so far), anonymizing some of it if you have to, someone will be happy to help you convert that to a table-valued function (hopefully an inline one).

Comment: If someone wanted to take a whack at it, I threw the proc on pastebin, no state secrets divulged here: http://pastebin.com/s8VDB4NT

Comment: @Tom yeah, that's a little excessive. You might want to ask for free help converting something similar but a lot smaller, and taking what you learn from that and applying it to your much larger procedure.

Comment: Totally excessive, figured maybe someone would take a stab for sport.  I'll give it a whirl myself and see what happens.  Not under too much pressure to deliver yet.  Going with your solution so you get the check.

Answer (score 2):

Often you can rewrite a stored proc as a table valued function, then it is a function - problem solved.